# Prepending letter to field value

Tags: bash, unix, field, text-processing, prepend

I have a file `0.txt` containing the following value fields contents in parentheses:

```
(bread,milk,),
(rice,brand B,),
(pan,eggs,Brandc,),
```

I'm looking in OS and elsewhere for how to prepend the letter `x` to the beginning of each value between commas so that my output file becomes (using bash unix):

```
(xbread,xmilk,),
(xrice,xbrand B,),
(xpan,xeggs,xBrand C,),
```

the only thing I've really tried but not enough is:

```
awk '{gsub(/,/,",x");print}' 0.txt
```

for all purposes the prefix should not be applied to the last commas at the end of each line.

Comment: I suggest to use `sed`: `sed -E 's/\b([^,]*)/x\1/g' 0.txt`

Comment: @Cyrus but with `sed` I would use a replacement method, in this case similar to what I did in the example with `awk gsub`, so how would I avoid replacing the last commas `,),`? Anyway I'll think and try something with `sed` and find out what you proposed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `awk`

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{$1="(x"substr($1,2);for(i=2;i<=NF-2;i++){$i="x"$i}}1'
```

Explanation:

```
# Before you start, set the input and output delimiter
BEGIN{
   FS=OFS=","
}

# The first field is special, the x has to be inserted
# after the opening (
$1="(x"substr($1,2)


# Prepend 'x' from field 2 until the previous to last field
for(i=2;i<=NF-2;i++){
    $i="x"$i
}

# 1 is always true. awk will print in that case
1
```

Answer (score 3):

The trick is to anchor the regexp so that it matches the whole comma-terminated substring you want to work with, not just the comma (and avoids other “special” characters in the syntax).

```sh
awk '{ gsub(/[^,()]+,/, "x&") } 1' 0.txt
```

```sh
sed -r 's/([^,()]+,)/x\1/g' 0.txt
```

Comment: One might definitely wonder why [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69669740/8584929) was not held to the same “standard”. Yes, this answer may not be of a “high quality”, but it simply responds to the code snippet from the question and makes it work. The tools in use (`awk` or `sed`) and the basic concept (regexps) are already obvious from the question. While I do agree with the “avoid code-only answers” idea, in a way, *none* of the bad examples linked there matches this scenario (== a small tweak to a snippet already posted by the OP).

Comment: Both this answer and the other answer triggered a "low quality answers" review in the review queue.   The explanation that you added does a lot to improve your answer.

Comment: Andrej - Stephen is just the latest user to decide rubber-stamping the tools "possibly low quality" flag without understanding the domain and so unable to tell if the answer actually is low quality or not is a good use of their time. It's not worth wasting your time engaging these people, they're just cluttering up the forum with nonsense. The code in your answer obviously needed no explanation.